# How to display errors with charka UI when submitting a formik form with untouched controls

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, chakra-ui

I've a form in react with charka UI + Formik.

I'm trying to integrate both of them properly based on what I found here: https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/with-formik. So far, I've this:

```
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Link as ChakraLink,
  Container,
  Divider,
  FormControl,
  FormErrorMessage,
  FormLabel,
  HStack,
  Heading,
  Input,
  Stack,
  Text,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Field, Formik } from "formik";
import { Link as ReactRouterLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Register() {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
      validate={(values) => {
        const errors: {
          email?: string;
          password?: string;
        } = {};
        if (!values.email) {
          console.log("email required");
          errors.email = "Required";
        } else if (
          !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(values.email)
        ) {
          console.log("email wrong fromat");
          errors.email = "Invalid email address";
        }
        if (!values.password) {
          console.log("password is required");
          errors.password = "Required";
        }
        return errors;
      }}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        alert("coucou");
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          setSubmitting(false);
        }, 400);
      }}
    >
      {({ errors, handleSubmit, touched }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Container
            maxW="lg"
            py={{ base: "12", md: "24" }}
            px={{ base: "0", sm: "8" }}
          >
            <Stack spacing="8">
              <Stack spacing="6">
                {/* <Logo /> */}
                <Stack spacing={{ base: "2", md: "3" }} textAlign="center">
                  <Heading size={{ base: "xs", md: "sm" }}>
                    Create a new account
                  </Heading>
                  <Text color="fg.muted">
                    Already have an account?
                    <ChakraLink as={ReactRouterLink} to={"/login"}>
                      Login
                    </ChakraLink>
                  </Text>
                </Stack>
              </Stack>
              <Box
                py={{ base: "0", sm: "8" }}
                px={{ base: "4", sm: "10" }}
                bg={{ base: "transparent", sm: "bg.surface" }}
                boxShadow={{ base: "none", sm: "md" }}
                borderRadius={{ base: "none", sm: "xl" }}
              >
                <Stack spacing="6">
                  <Stack spacing="5">
                    <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.email && touched.email}>
                      <FormLabel htmlFor="email">Email</FormLabel>
                      <FormErrorMessage>{errors.email}</FormErrorMessage>
                      <Field id="email" name="email" type="email" as={Input} />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl
                      isInvalid={!!errors.password && touched.password}
                    >
                      <FormLabel htmlFor="password">Password</FormLabel>
                      <FormErrorMessage>{errors.password}</FormErrorMessage>
                      <Field
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        as={Input}
                        autoComplete="new-password"
                        required
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                  </Stack>
                  <HStack justify="space-between"></HStack>
                  <Stack spacing="6">
                    <Button type="submit">Register</Button>
                    <HStack>
                      <Divider />
                      <Text textStyle="sm" whiteSpace="nowrap" color="fg.muted">
                        or continue with
                      </Text>
                      <Divider />
                    </HStack>
                    {/* <OAuthButtonGroup /> */}
                  </Stack>
                </Stack>
              </Box>
            </Stack>
          </Container>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

But if I try to validate my form without any values, I see my two `console.log`(email is required and password is required), but I don't see any visual indicator.

I think it's becaused the fields are not considered as "touched" ? How can I fix this? I thought that formik would set all fields as touched when submitting forms?